# Writing a function inside a PL/SQL page

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I want to create a function that do a specific task inside a oracle package, I tried with the bellow code, but it gives an error that I don't understand.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE DINIDU_EXE_PACKAGE AS

FUNCTION EXE14 
(SUP_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.SUPPLIER_ID%TYPE,PAR_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.PART_ID%TYPE,PRO_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.PROJECT_ID%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER IS

QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_ NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT QUENTITY AS QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_ FROM SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB WHERE SUPPLIER_ID=SUP_ID AND PART_ID=PAR_ID AND PRO_ID=PROJECT_ID;

    IF QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_ >0 THEN

      RETURN QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;

    END IF;

END EXE14;

END;
```

**Error(6,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_" when expecting one of the following:     language**

Comment: Function definition should be placed inside package body, not inside package specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Egor is right in his comment. You are putting a function in to the package specification while it has to be in package body instead.

Only a reference to a function or its signature - function name and arguments list - have to be in the package specification. The actual function has to be coded in the body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE DINIDU_EXE_PACKAGE AS
    FUNCTION EXE14 
    ( SUP_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.SUPPLIER_ID%TYPE
    , PAR_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.PART_ID%TYPE
    ,PRO_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.PROJECT_ID%TYPE)
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY DINIDU_EXE_PACKAGE AS
    FUNCTION EXE14 
    ( SUP_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.SUPPLIER_ID%TYPE
    , PAR_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.PART_ID%TYPE
    ,PRO_ID_ SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB.PROJECT_ID%TYPE)
RETURN NUMBER IS
    QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_ NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT QUENTITY AS QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_ FROM SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB WHERE SUPPLIER_ID=SUP_ID AND PART_ID=PAR_ID AND PRO_ID=PROJECT_ID;

    IF QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_ >0 THEN

      RETURN QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;

    END IF;

END EXE14;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: see Egor's comment and Rachcha's answer for the actual cause of the compilation error.

Your code first declares `QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_` as a local variable, but then your `SELECT` statement uses the same identifier as a column alias (`QUENTITY AS QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_`). More importantly, you have not selected the result `INTO` anything.

I think you meant to do something like this:

```
SELECT QUENTITY INTO QUNTITY_FOR_A_PROJECT_ FROM SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB ...
```

Another problem: your function accepts the following parameters: `SUP_ID_`, `PAR_ID_` and `PRO_ID_`, but you don't use them in your function. I suspect the identifiers are not used correctly in the query, but I cannot know for sure because I don't know what the columns of your `SUPPLIER_PART_PROJECT_TAB` table are.

Comment: Thank you for your help Jeffery, actually it was due to my lack of knowledge about pl/sql packages.